# How can I get the bounding box values of all the text elements in a selection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got a D3 selection like this:

```
const labels = svg.selectAll('text').data(data);
labels.enter().append('text')
    .attr('class', (d) => `label-${d.label}`)
    .attr('x', (d) => scale.x(d.time))
    .attr('y', (d) => scale.y(d.value))
    .text((d) => `${d.answer}`);
```

Given the above code, how would I be able to get the bounding box of all text elements created? I'm looking to do something similar to how Mike Bostock gets the bounding box of one text element in the following code: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1160929. However, I'd like to get the bounding box values of each element, so I can create a `rect` element for each text element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
...
.text((d) => `${d.answer}`)
.each(function(d){
  var bbox = this.getBBox();
  svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x', bbox.x)
    .attr('y', bbox.y)
    .attr('width', bbox.width)
    .attr('height', bbox.height)
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('stroke', 'steelblue');
  });
```

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chance/1.0.8/chance.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var w = 300,
          h = 300;
      var data = [
        {
          x: Math.random() * (w - 100),
          y: Math.random() * h,
          t: chance.word()
        },{
          x: Math.random() * (w - 100),
          y: Math.random() * h,
          t: chance.word()
        },{
          x: Math.random() * (w - 100),
          y: Math.random() * h,
          t: chance.word()
        },{
          x: Math.random() * (w - 100),
          y: Math.random() * h,
          t: chance.word()
        },{
          x: Math.random() * (w - 100),
          y: Math.random() * h,
          t: chance.word()
        },{
          x: Math.random() * (w - 100),
          y: Math.random() * h,
          t: chance.word()
        },{
          x: Math.random() * (w - 100),
          y: Math.random() * h,
          t: chance.word()
        },{
          x: Math.random() * (w - 100),
          y: Math.random() * h,
          t: chance.word()
        },{
          x: Math.random() * (w - 100),
          y: Math.random() * h,
          t: chance.word()
        },{
          x: Math.random() * (w - 100),
          y: Math.random() * h,
          t: chance.word()
        },{
          x: Math.random() * (w - 100),
          y: Math.random() * h,
          t: chance.word()
        },{
          x: Math.random() * (w - 100),
          y: Math.random() * h,
          t: chance.word()
        },{
          x: Math.random() * (w - 100),
          y: Math.random() * h,
          t: chance.word()
        }
      ]
      
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', w)
        .attr('height', h);
      
      const labels = svg.selectAll('text').data(data);
      
      labels.enter()
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', (d) => `label-${d.t}`)
        .attr('x', (d) => d.x)
        .attr('y', (d) =>d.y)
        .text((d) => d.t)
        .each(function(d){
          var bbox = this.getBBox();
          svg.append('rect')
            .attr('x', bbox.x)
            .attr('y', bbox.y)
            .attr('width', bbox.width)
            .attr('height', bbox.height)
            .style('fill', 'none')
            .style('stroke', 'steelblue');
        });
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I had to go `.each((d, i, j) => {const bbox = j[i].getBBox(); ... }` to accomplish this but your code works. Thanks

Comment: @Benjamin, it's because you are using fat arrow notation and not a regular function.  `=>`, by design, suppresses the passing of `this` into the function.